OpenGL instanced meshes rendering incorrectly when instances differ
Context:
I'm working on instancing in OpenGL (version 4.6) using C++ and SDL for window creation. When I render multiple instances of a quad:

If all instances are identical, the rendering works perfectly.
If I try to make the instances different (e.g. using different model matrices), the instances render incorrectly. It seems like only one instance is rendered, and the vertices are displaced randomly.

Here's the relevant code for setting up and rendering the instances:
Code for instance data setup:
std::vector<glm::mat4> instances;
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int x = i % 10;
    int y = i / 10;

    if (i == 0) instances.push_back(glm::translate(glm::mat4{ 1.0 }, glm::vec3{5.0, 0.0, 0.0}));
    else instances.push_back(glm::translate(glm::mat4{ 1.0 }, glm::vec3{ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }));
}

uint32_t instanceBuffer;
glCreateBuffers(1, &instanceBuffer);
glNamedBufferStorage(instanceBuffer, sizeof(glm::mat4) * instances.size(), instances.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT);

uint32_t vao = mesh->vao;

uint32_t location = 3;
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(vao, location + i);
    glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, location + i, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, i * sizeof(glm::vec4));
    glVertexArrayAttribBinding(vao, location + i, 1);
    glVertexArrayBindingDivisor(vao, location + i, 1);
}

glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, 1, instanceBuffer, 0, sizeof(glm::mat4));

Code for drawing:
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glUseProgram(defaultShader->id);

UniformManager::SetMat4(defaultShader, "u_ProjectionView", projectionView);

glBindVertexArray(vao);

UniformManager::SetInt(defaultShader, "u_IsInstance", true);
glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, mesh->count, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr, (uint32_t)instances.size());

Vertex shader:
#version 460 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 vPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 vNorm;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 vTexCoords;
layout (location = 3) in mat4 vInstance;

out vec2 vertexUV;

uniform bool u_IsInstance;

uniform mat4 u_ProjectionView;
uniform mat4 u_Model;

void main() {
    vertexUV = vTexCoords;
    if (!u_IsInstance) 
        gl_Position = u_ProjectionView * u_Model * vec4(vPos, 1.0);
    else 
        gl_Position = u_ProjectionView * vInstance * vec4(vPos, 1.0);
}

What I've tried:

Verified that instanceBuffer contains the correct data (double-checked with a debugger).
Ensured vao is correctly configured with attributes and bindings.
Checked the shader logic, which works correctly without instancing.

Additional context:

OpenGL version: 4.6 (using Direct State Access for setup).
The rendering works fine when all instances are identical (e.g., same vInstance matrix).
When different instance data is used, the result looks like only one instance is rendered, and its geometry is displaced randomly.

Screenshots:
Correct rendering with identical instances:

Incorrect rendering with different instances:

Question:
Why does my rendering break when I use different instance data? Am I missing something in the buffer setup, data alignment, or shader configuration?
